# 12V lighted rocker switch getting hot even without load

Tags: switches, light, overheat

Is it normal that 12v lighted rocker switches get hot even when the load is not connected? Attached is the schematic and the PCB layout for such switch: https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Rocker-Switches_ROCKTEK-RT-S02-113-R42BR_C309263.html

The switches get very hot, the ones with more load get even hotter.

[image](VCC is 12V)
[image]

Comment: `ones with more load get even hotter` makes sense if the contacts are being overloaded

Comment: @jsotola it can burn one's finger when there is not load. The led itself shouldn't overload the contact the switch.

Comment: it is unclear if the indicator is an LED ... pins 1 and 3 are probably shorting internally ... check the switch with an ohmmeter

Comment: datasheet says: "The usable lamp life has not been evaluated". *lol* Now you know why. SCNR. I recommend measuring the current through the lamp and maybe reduce it by adding resistors or diodes to the ground pin.

Answer (score 3):

You say "12V" in your title, and "12V" in your message, so presume "12V" is not a typo.
But the datasheet you linked (which matches the part number on your schematic) clearly indicates that switch is meant to run it's light from 125V...

Meaning - You got the wrong datasheet

If the datasheet/part number are wrong, perhaps something else is wrong too.

Like...

Suppose you think you have a 12V drive lamp, but it's really meant to be driven on 5V.  That'd explain why it gets so hot.

Or...

The pinout isn't what you think it is

Or...

Just take one of the switches apart.  They're not magic.  You'll figure out quickly by examining the mechanism if the switch is different from what you expect.